# Overlay information ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add two different scales of colours to my data.

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
    Exp1       Exp2      Cells    Sample colors
 -3.4397902   10.058648 0.2666572  5_2   yellow
  0.992361    4.272414  0.0000000  7_1   pink
  3.2959178   7.605405  0.4300744  5_2   yellow
 -6.7069208   5.652064  0.0000000  7_1   pink
 -2.5130817   3.703727  0.0000000  7_1   pink
 -8.5677462   7.570862  0.0000000  5_2   yellow
```

To do this I used the following piece of code:

> ```
> ggplot(mydata) +
>   geom_point(aes(Exp1, Exp2, color=Cells))  +
>   geom_point(aes(Exp1, Exp2, group=colors, alpha=colors), size=1) + scale_colour_gradient2(low="blue",mid="orange" , high="pink")
> ```

I'm able to plot the gradient but I'm not able to plot yellow dots and pink dots according to the Sample of origin.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to work with fill and color independently

```
ggplot(d) +
  geom_point(aes(Exp1, Exp2, color=Cells))  +
  geom_point(aes(Exp1, Exp2, fill=colors), shape=21, size=1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "yellow")) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low="blue",mid="orange" , high="pink")
```

[image]